# jQuery LazyLoad for New Image Loaded From Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have this code works for images loaded for the first time :

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("img.lazy").lazyload({
            effect : "fadeIn",
            threshold : 200
        });
    });
</script>
```

but for new images loaded from AJAX, it's not working. I read by using event delegation, it can be applied to new loaded images.

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

but when I tried to change my code into this :

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("img.lazy").lazyload( function(event) {
            effect : "fadeIn",
            threshold : 200
        });
    });
</script>
```

it makes all lazyload is not working anymore. how to attach event delegation correctly in this case? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **jQuery Global Ajax Event Handler** `.ajaxSuccess()`.

This a function that will be executed whenever an Ajax request completes successfully.

Try something like this, assuming your AJAX response is plain HTML. 
The code searches all the images with the class `.lazy` in the response, and binds the `lazyload()` function to them.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings ) {

    // the response in stored in `xhr.responseText`
    $(xhr.responseText).find('img.lazy').lazyload({
        effect : "fadeIn",
        threshold : 200
    });

});
```

You can read more about **Global Ajax Event Handlers** here:
https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: I've assumed that your response is HTML. If not, tell me and I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: actually, the next page will be loaded is load using infinite-scroll plugin. so, yes it's HTML.

Comment: Ok, so I think that the code I've written is just fine. Let me know if it works.

Comment: What if response was in json format? I really need a solution.

Comment: provide a minimal reproducible example (https://jsfiddle.net/) and I will try to offer a solution.

Answer (score -1):

in my experience, you need a call back function to run javascript on the element you read by Ajax.

For example:

```
var listname = [];   


 $.ajax({
    url : wedding, // change to your local url or url on the same domain, this not work with absolute url
    success: function (data) {
       callback(data);
    }
});

function callback(data) {
      $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
             //   $('#displayImage1').append( "<img src='" + wedding + val +"'>" );
                 listname.push(val);
            } 
        });
}
```